# Date Format Changes while concatenating frames in Pandas Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I would like to concatenate two frames. Can do so as well. 
However, while doing so date format is auto changing which is untended and needs to resolve. I've a column called EVENT_DATE in **'YYYY-MM-DD'** format. But its being changed.

**Here loading a sample TSV formatted data to data frame**

```
>>>df1 = pd.read_csv('detail_trend_analysis_data.csv',delimiter='|', parse_dates=[0])
>>>df1.head()
  EVENT_DATE  EVENT_HOUR  PRODUCT  ...  BONUS_VOLUME     BONUS_COST  RECORD_COUNT
0 2019-11-08           0        1  ...           0.0  220152.426342        287516
1 2019-11-08           0        1  ...           0.0       0.000000          3104
2 2019-11-08           0        1  ...           0.0  226544.777596        254965
3 2019-11-08           0        1  ...           0.0       0.000000          2449
4 2019-11-08           0        1  ...           0.0       0.000000         35085
[5 rows x 18 columns]
```

**Doing Same thing**

```
>>>df2 = pd.read_csv('detail_trend_analysis_data.csv',delimiter='|', parse_dates=[0])
```

**Changing the date**

```
>>>df2['EVENT_DATE']='2019-11-09'
>>>df2.head()
   EVENT_DATE  EVENT_HOUR  PRODUCT  ...  BONUS_VOLUME     BONUS_COST  RECORD_COUNT
0  2019-11-09           0        1  ...           0.0  220152.426342        287516
1  2019-11-09           0        1  ...           0.0       0.000000          3104
2  2019-11-09           0        1  ...           0.0  226544.777596        254965
3  2019-11-09           0        1  ...           0.0       0.000000          2449
4  2019-11-09           0        1  ...           0.0       0.000000         35085
[5 rows x 18 columns]
```

**Concatenating**

```
>>>frames=[df1,df2]
>>>df=pd.concat(frames)
>>>df.head()
            EVENT_DATE  EVENT_HOUR  ...     BONUS_COST  RECORD_COUNT
0  2019-11-08 00:00:00           0  ...  220152.426342        287516
1  2019-11-08 00:00:00           0  ...       0.000000          3104
2  2019-11-08 00:00:00           0  ...  226544.777596        254965
3  2019-11-08 00:00:00           0  ...       0.000000          2449
4  2019-11-08 00:00:00           0  ...       0.000000         35085
[5 rows x 18 columns]
```

But at the end time changes to 'YYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' which I don't want. 
How to resolve this?

Comment: can you check the dtypes of the both the data frames

Comment: dtype of df1 is dtype('<M8[ns]') and dtype of df2 is dtype('O'). Bit strange as I just copied it. Shouldn't it be the same?

Comment: so try to set the dtype of df2 to datetime

Comment: Done this: `df2['EVENT_DATE']=pd.to_datetime(df2.EVENT_DATE)` then concatenated. Its working fine now.

Comment: Cool, good to know :)

Comment: Getting the same issues in pandas 1.1.5 (in my case changing ints of the constituent dataframes to float).

Answer (score 0):

what if you set df['EVENT_DATE] = df['EVENT_DATE'].dt.date on both dataframes?